# Does a decorator run once even if the decorated function was called many times?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

so this code is supposed to count how many times a functions is called, but I'm trying to understand decorating in python more deeply and not just copying code, by running this code below

```
def counter(func):
    print('counter function executed')
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('wrapper function executed')
        wrapper.count += 1
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.count = 0
    return wrapper

@counter
def foo(i):
    return print(f'{i}')

foo('foo')
foo('foo')
foo('foo')
print(foo.count)
```

it outputs

```
counter function executed
wrapper function executed
foo
wrapper function executed
foo
wrapper function executed
foo
3
```

but decorating `foo()` should equal `counter(foo)`

why `"counter function executed"` was printed once ?? isn't it supposed to be printed every time `foo()` is called, does that mean decorating `foo()` actually equals to `wrapper(foo)` .... am I getting it right ???

I came to this conclusion because I thought that `wrapper.counter` would always equal `0` as `counter(foo)` would reset `wrapper.counter` value to `0`.

Comment: *Decorating* isn't the same as *calling the decorated function*. The act of decorating is one function call, the call to the decorated function is another. The decorated function is `wrapper`, not `counter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decorator runs only at the time the decorated function is defined, in order to modify the function definition.  The function returned by the decorator (`wrapper`) is what gets executed each time the decorated function is called.